# Configurable product Add configurations visibility

Tags: magento2

Is there any way of setting new created products from within a configurable product to **visibility** *search* insted of *not visible individually*?

Comment: If you use visibility to search or catalog search for simple products under configurable products then simples products will be also listed on product list and search page. You can set search or catalog search for simples.

Comment: Ok I was thinking about the visibility of the child products that are created from a configurable product.

Comment: If the simples are created from configurable then the visibility will be always Not visible individually. you can change the visibility after product creation if needed.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, can we show those child items in frontend if they are out of stock, i have set the option to show out of stock products, only child items are not showing.All remaining simple product are shown.